# Does this use case fit Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

We are getting stock market data from an commercial API, currently using AWS Lambda scheduled to run every minute to store and we store the recent data in MongoDB.

The goal is to do some data-warehouse style pre-computations to make querying and decision making easier. So for example, we compare the current price to several intervals back, for example:

```
listIntervalsInMinutes = [1, 5, 10, 15, 30, 60, 90, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360, 390]
```

We also look at the last 15 minutes of each stock to see if the price went up or down. So to do the computations requires looking about 27 records from history during the same day.  We don't overlap one day to the other at this time.

[In Python, we load the 9305 tickers into a ManagedList, then spawn off multiple processes to pop one ticker/symbol off the list, process it, store the results back in MongoDB).  It keeps running until the ManagedList is empty, then it starts all over by putting the original list of ticker/symbols back in the ManagedList.]

The program works for a few selected ticker/symbols, but there are 9350 ticker/symbols in total. We've got it doing multiprocessing in Python, and on a server with 32 processors, but still doing the math, it will be impossible to keep up with the flow of new data and do the interval computations.

Would Apache Spark help with this?

If that doesn't fit, our next approach is to save a minimal amount of data in REDIS to speed up the access time.

If Spark might be a fit, does it really do anything better than running Python on multiple servers?  In other words, if I need 5 more servers to process the data, would I also probably need 5 or more servers with Spark?  It it's main purpose just to scale out by adding more servers when needed?

Comment: Seems like a good fit for Spark (streaming, if that's how you're receiving the data?). And google seems to bring up a lot of content on related use cases. One thing for sure is that spark will solve your scale challenge, but the key of the rest is going to be how spark's model is adopted/implemented in your application.

Comment: The data is not exactly streamed.  We call an API every one minute. I supposed that program could publish the data to Spark.

Comment: I was just making a guess. Doesn't have to be streamed, but I'm speculating that streaming will be the model you want for such a continuous analysis that queries based on incoming records (and I think there are ways to do streaming off a database, or you could use a queue/topic that your API client would feed). But you can still do batch processing for this

Comment: @NealWalters How frequently you want to compute the result for each ticket? every minute ?

Comment: @Samlet9394 - yes, every minute, or as close as possible to it.

Comment: @NealWalters Using a Cache (AWS elastic cache) makes more sense. with a key of <ticker-timestamp> with expiry time of 400 mins. So, you will have maximum of 4M (400 * 10000) items at any time. Now each thread of your python would fetch those 27 datapoints in under `1ms`. So, assuming you have 30 active threads : Overall time will be  `((1ms  + computation time on those 27 points )*10000/30)`

Comment: For Spark Your job requires to maintain at least 4M items in memory which is ok. But now filtering for those 27 datapoints will be definitely much much slower than a Cache.